# headers get sent even after output in php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers

I am facing this problem for quite a while. Even if I output lots of thing before my headers, still my headers are being sent.
NOTE: I have disabled output_buffering in my php.ini

**View:** (`headers.php`)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> BLAH </title>
</head>

<body>
<p> TEXT </p>
<?php
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    echo "something";
    header("Content-type: text/html");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get("header", function(){
    return View::make("headers"); 
});
```

Comment: Where this code is written? Is this inside any class/method? Please clarify your question.

Comment: this is written in my headers.php and this is the whole content of that file i have put up on my question

Comment: Is this `headers.php` a class, how do you access this `class/method` ?

Comment: you are confusing me a bit. This is not a class

Comment: You are completely confusing me because you are using `Laravel` and not using any route or controller class then how do you access/run this `header.php` file, how do you run this script ?

Comment: okay. I am using route
Route::get("header", function(){
    return View::make("headers");
});

Comment: Where is the code ? in your `headers` view ?

Comment: You don't send the headers; instead `Laravel` sends it and response is handled by response class.

Comment: okay i understood, but just one more thing when I use var_dump("headers_list()") in my code, this is printed 
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12' (length=24)
  1 => string 'Pragma: no-cache' (length=16)
  2 => string 'Content-type: text/html' (length=23)

any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The response is handled by `Laravel`'s `Response` class and this class sends the response back to the `client/browser` and `Laravel` sets the headers. In your example, you are returning the view and in your view whatever is present, the `Laravel` framework will render those and then the rendered output will be sent to the `client/browser`.

> You asked about headers_list

Check on `PHP` manual about [headers_list()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.headers-list.php):

> headers_list — Returns a list of response headers sent (or ready to
>   send)

Here `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12` is your `PHP` version and is a response header.